# Created simple App with WL.Client.connect and mobile web environment, see "Access Denied" when running it on the preview and actual device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Created a simple hybrid app.  Only have the following in the code

### main.js

```
function wlCommonInit() {
   WL.Client.connect({
      onSuccess: function() {alert ("OK");},
      onFailure: function (string) {alert ("fail" + string);}
   });
}
```

I created a mobile web environment.

After I did a Build All Environment, Run it on the Server.
I right click on the mobile web environment > Preview

I kept getting a pop up alert saying "Access Denied" with a button named reload

I moved to my iphone and in the safari, typed in the URL for the mobile web.  I got exactly the same error on my iphone.

Please assist.  [image: This is what it looks like on iphone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us what version of MobileFirst Platform Foundation you are using, but I am guessing that it is 7.1.

In 7.1, a new [Session-Independent Mode](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/t_upgrading_projects_session_depend.html) was introduced, and is turned on by default.  However, session-independent mode is not supported in browser-based environments (such as mobile web).  If you try to use an app that's configured for session-independent mode in an environment that doesn't support it, you will get this error.  If you want to create an app in 7.1 that uses a browser-based environment, you'll need to disable session-independent mode.

If you go into your project's "worklight.properties" file, set (or change) these values:

```
mfp.session.independent=false
mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession
```

and then rebuild/deploy your project, it should work.

Please see the doc page I've linked above for further information about session-independent mode.